# Appium Parallel Execution + TestNG Framework issue

Tags: multithreading, testing, automation, testng, appium

I Just started creating a framework for appium. I am facing challenges when i am trying to create driver.

It starts as follows

Step 1: Based on the thread count and devices i will be creating appium servers at runtime in TestNG's @Beforesuite.

```
    cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Dev1");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, udid);
    //Build the Appium service
    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
    builder.usingAnyFreePort();
    builder.withCapabilities(cap);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error");

    appiumservice = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    appiumservice.start();
```

Step 2: I will get the appium server url's for all devices connected using

```
appiumservice.getUrl().toString()
```

Now i have all server url's and Capabilities.

The question is now in TestNG.xml if i give Parallel and thread-count to 3 how can i set create a AndroidDriver object in @BeforeMethod in such a way each time it should take different appium server url and execute the tests ?
How should my @Beforemethod and @Aftermethod  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass port and device from testng : 

<suite name="Suite" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
<parameter name="properties" value="XXX" />
<tests>
<test name="Run on device 1">
<classes>
<parameter name="port" value="4723"/>
<parameter name="device" value="DeviceID1"></parameter>
<class name="com.testScripts.ABC">
<methods>
  <include name="test1"/>   
</methods>
</class>
</classes>
</test>
<test name="run on device 2">
<classes>
<parameter name="port" value="4724"></parameter>
<parameter name="device" value="DeviceID2"></parameter>
<class name="com.testScripts.ABC">
<methods>
<include name="test1"/>
</methods>
</class>
</classes>
</test>
</tests>
</suite> 


Put following annotation in method whrere you are defining your capability ..
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun=true)
@Parameters({"port","device"}) 
Public void capablities()
{
cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, device);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, udid);
    //Build the Appium service
    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
    //use port pass in testng file
    // builder.usingAnyFreePort();
    builder.withCapabilities(cap);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error");

    appiumservice = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    appiumservice.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shiv, But i have couple of questions on the solution provided. Do you want me to create driver object in @beforemethod ? will parallel execution will automatically take care for different driverobjects for the parameters provided ? lets say one thread in http://127.0.0,1:4723/wd/hub and other http://127.0.0.1:4724/wd/hub

Comment: Based on your parameter provided for device and port it  will create  ...n .. number of instances  127.0.0,1:4723/wd/hub  ,  127.0.0,1:4724/wd/hub ... stating parallel in tesng will execute <test> defined under <tests> tag in parallel way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest initialising the driver in the @BeforeClass method, and as shiv mentioned use TestNG parameters:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:"+ port +"/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```